# ng-click fires twice in directive controlled navigation

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that I am using to render my navigation but there are two ng-clicks in it and both of them fire twice when clicked. I have read similar questions on here but still can't work it out. Any input would be much appreciated.

The html element

```
<nav ng-cloak ig-nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation"></nav>
```

The js

```
.controller('navCtrl',
  ['$scope', function($scope){
    console.log('navCtrl');
    $scope.usermenu = false;
    $scope.toggleMenu = function() {
      var nv = !$scope.usermenu;
      console.log(nv);
      $scope.usermenu = nv;
    };
 }])

.directive('igNav', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'partials/nav.html',
    controller: 'navCtrl'
  };
})
```

And the nav template

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li ng-if="auth.user"><a href="#/add" title="Add new asset"><!--i class="icon-plus"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add</a></li>
  <li ng-if="auth.user"><a href="#/share" data-toggle="modal" title="Share tags"><!--i class="icon-share"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span> Share</a></li>
  <li ng-if="auth.user" class="dropdown" ng-class="{open: usermenu}">
    <a href="#" ng-click="toggleMenu()" class="truncate">{{user.name}} <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#/activity"><!--i class="icon-align-left"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span> Activity</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/shares"><!--i class="icon-truck"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> Shares</a></li>
      <li class="divider">&nbsp;</li>
      <li><a href="#/account"><!--i class="icon-cog"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()" title="Logout - {{user.name}}"><!--i class="icon-signout"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li ng-if="!auth.user"><a href="#/login"><!--i class="icon-signin"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

As it has worked in charliefl's plnkr there must be some other reason it is firing twice. Here is some more info I thought was irrelevant but perhaps it is after all.

The app is running firebase and angularfire 0.5.
$route has been included.
Angular is manually inialized.
ignav is included inside a base level controller (applied to the HTML tag)

Comment: seems to work fine here...http://plnkr.co/edit/ZiUQTpE8Ilq872F9fVyq?p=preview

Comment: Then perhaps there is another reason. Have added additional content to post about the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite working in the fiddle in my app it was still firing twice.
After a bit of reorganising the simple fix was moving the ng-click from the `<a>` to its parent `<li>`

```
<li ng-if="auth.user" ng-click="toggleMenu()" class="dropdown" ng-class="{open: usermenu}">
  <a href="#" class="truncate">{{user.name}} <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#/activity"><!--i class="icon-align-left"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></span> Activity</a></li>
    <li><a href="#/shares"><!--i class="icon-truck"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span> Shares</a></li>
    <li class="divider">&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href="#/account"><!--i class="icon-cog"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="logout()" title="Logout - {{user.name}}"><!--i class="icon-signout"></i--><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span> Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```